# How can I recompile Bootstrap so that my theme color changes in _variables.scss when I am using Angular with CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-5

So far I have found the SCSS file `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss` to change the primary color for example and I have stopped npm and run the front-end again but changes in that file are not shown in the actual behaviour.

My guess is that it's because I need to recompile Bootstrap but as I have never used SCSS and my Angular project uses CSS I have no idea nor I could find an easy explanation on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TODO:

1. create a variable.scss file in your project and write this

```
$primary: red;
```

2. in your main.scss file

```
@import 'variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstarp'
```

3. compile it.

[here is the example](https://github.com/monzoor/rm-task/blob/master/client/src/Assets/scss/App.scss)

NOTE: like this you can modify every variables that BS used.

Comment: How do I ```compile it```? Do I stop ```ng serve```and run it again @MonzoorTamal ?

Comment: you need to compile the scss files. here is the example https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli

Comment: You dont need to convert your css file to scss. You just need to import your css file in the scss file. If you dont want to use sass at all. then compile your BS theme in somewhere else and add that compiled css file in your project