# Bootstrap 5 map for color levels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, scss-mixins

In Bootstrap 5 docs, _colors.scss has the following classes:

```
.bd-blue-100 { color: color-contrast($blue-100); background-color: $blue-100; }
.bd-blue-200 { color: color-contrast($blue-200); background-color: $blue-200; }
.bd-blue-300 { color: color-contrast($blue-300); background-color: $blue-300; }
.bd-blue-400 { color: color-contrast($blue-400); background-color: $blue-400; }
.bd-blue-500 { color: color-contrast($blue-500); background-color: $blue-500; }
.bd-blue-600 { color: color-contrast($blue-600); background-color: $blue-600; }
.bd-blue-700 { color: color-contrast($blue-700); background-color: $blue-700; }
.bd-blue-800 { color: color-contrast($blue-800); background-color: $blue-800; }
.bd-blue-900 { color: color-contrast($blue-900); background-color: $blue-900; }

.bd-indigo-100 { color: color-contrast($indigo-100); background-color: $indigo-100; }
.bd-indigo-200 { color: color-contrast($indigo-200); background-color: $indigo-200; }
.bd-indigo-300 { color: color-contrast($indigo-300); background-color: $indigo-300; }
.bd-indigo-400 { color: color-contrast($indigo-400); background-color: $indigo-400; }
.bd-indigo-500 { color: color-contrast($indigo-500); background-color: $indigo-500; }
.bd-indigo-600 { color: color-contrast($indigo-600); background-color: $indigo-600; }
.bd-indigo-700 { color: color-contrast($indigo-700); background-color: $indigo-700; }
.bd-indigo-800 { color: color-contrast($indigo-800); background-color: $indigo-800; }
.bd-indigo-900 { color: color-contrast($indigo-900); background-color: $indigo-900; }

.bd-purple-100 { color: color-contrast($purple-100); background-color: $purple-100; }
.bd-purple-200 { color: color-contrast($purple-200); background-color: $purple-200; }
.bd-purple-300 { color: color-contrast($purple-300); background-color: $purple-300; }
.bd-purple-400 { color: color-contrast($purple-400); background-color: $purple-400; }
.bd-purple-500 { color: color-contrast($purple-500); background-color: $purple-500; }
.bd-purple-600 { color: color-contrast($purple-600); background-color: $purple-600; }
.bd-purple-700 { color: color-contrast($purple-700); background-color: $purple-700; }
.bd-purple-800 { color: color-contrast($purple-800); background-color: $purple-800; }
.bd-purple-900 { color: color-contrast($purple-900); background-color: $purple-900; }

and so on...
```

Each color level is defined in _variables.scss

How to generate these classes with .scss loops and maps instead of manually writing each level for each color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recompile Bootstrap so that my theme color changes in \_variables.scss when I am using Angular with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324908/how-can-i-recompile-bootstrap-so-that-my-theme-color-changes-in-variables-scss) Even if title is about angular, subject is same as yours.

Comment: Not really. Basically I want all those classes to be generated automatically from the defined colors in variables.